# asp.net mvc dynamic search criteria base on dropdownlist selection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Good morning, I am very new to asp.net mvc. I would like to develop a small application where user can search using criteria base on drop down selection. It means that when they select an option, a dynamic form elements will be created and initialized.

Here is the main screen it should be

[image]

as example, when user select Company then the page display like this

[image]

here are my script:

**My Controller**

```
 public class RequesterController : Controller
    {
        private mEntities db = new mEntities();
        public List<SelectListItem>  LoadSelectionList(){
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--- Select ---", Value = "0" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Available Sticker", Value = "1" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Company", Value = "2" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Interval Date", Value = "3" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Name", Value = "4" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Reference Number", Value = "5" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Interval Request Date", Value = "6" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Valide Start Date", Value = "7" });

            return li;           
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string dllSearchCategory, string ddlCategory, string ddlCompany, string searchString){
            ViewData["selectionlist"] = LoadSelectionList();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)){
             users = users.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }            
             return View(users);
        }

        public PartialViewResult LoadPartialGui(int id){
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> iCompanies = null;

            switch (id) {
                case 1: { //Available Sticker

                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                    { //Company
                         iCompanies = db.Companies
                                        .ToList()
                                        .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName)
                                        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Value = c.CompanyID.ToString(),
                                            Text = c.CompanyName
                                        });

                        ViewBag.Companies = iCompanies;

                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    { //Interval Date

                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    { //Name

                        break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    { //Reference Number

                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    { //Interval Request Date

                        break;
                    }
                case 7:
                    { //Valide Start Date

                        break;
                    }
            }
            return PartialView("LoadPartialGuiView", iCompanies);
        }     
    }
```

**My Partial View - LoadPartialGuiView **

```
@if (ViewBag.Companies != null) { 
    <fieldset>
        @Html.Label("Value: ")
        @Html.DropDownList("ddlCompany", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Companies, "--- Select ---")<br />
    </fieldset>
}
```

**And My Index.cshtml**

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Requester", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <p>
        Search By
        @Html.DropDownList("dllSearchCategory", ViewData["selectionlist"] as List<SelectListItem>)
        <div id="partialPlaceHolder"> </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    }

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FamilyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Company.CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DocumentPath)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoPath)
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FamilyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DocumentPath)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoPath)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.UserID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.UserID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('#dllSearchCategory').change(function () {       
        var selectedID = $(this).val();       
        $.get('/Requester/LoadPartialGui/' + selectedID, function (data) {       
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);            
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
        });       
    });    
</script>
```

When I click on Search button, the dynamic block created base of dropdownlist selection is also reset. I have no idea how can I make thing work.

Your help would be very much appreciated,

Regards,

Veasna

Comment: Not clear what you require. Is the table data based on the value of the first dropdown or the second dropdown or both? When you select from the first dropdown, should the table be cleared and then only rendered with new data when the second dropdown is selected?

Comment: So sorry, may be my explanation is not clear enough to get people understand my problem. What I would like to do is that when user select Search By: Company from first dropdownlist, then the page dynamic create second dropdown list and populate company data to it, and when user select Search By: Name, then dropdownlist Company is deleted, and page dynamic create textbox for user to input the name. The table below is the result of clicking search button base on critical from dropdownlist Company or TextBox Name.

Comment: A lot of what your doing here does not make sense. Of course the dropdown selection is 'reset' - your rendering a new view. And what is `searchString` in the `Index()` method?. I suggest you use AJAX to create a cascading select for the second dropdown (returning JSON to create the options) and render the table data in the change event of the second dropdown (returning partial view)